# We, the users of worldbuilding, are all gods. Can there be harmony amongst us?

Tags: alternate-reality, gods

We, the users of worldbuilding, are all gods.

We can create any number of alternate realities.

We can only be in one reality at a time.

We can shape these realities into whatever worlds we can imagine. We can make the worlds that we build a reality.

Being gods, we can travel to other realities and change them as we see fit.

We can also destroy any reality we desire by visiting that reality and shutting it down.

Moving from reality to reality causes a small connection to be formed between those two realities. The more we move from reality to reality the more this connection grows, until eventually the two realities start leaking onto each other. This can have profound effects on the inhabitants on both realities.

If two or more realities leak into each other too much they will eventually collapse (eventually being an extremely long amount of time), completely eliminating anything in those realities except for the gods themselves.

As well as creating flora and fauna, we can create a vast array of intelligent life forms to populate our realities. All intelligent life forms have their own free will. The intelligent life doesn't have to recognise you as a god, but having a popular belief system based upon you is a highly regarded status symbol amongst other gods.

Although we can create all manner of intelligent life in these realities, ultimately these intelligent life forms can never truly relate to us, and given enough time, we become lonely and crave the companionship of other gods.

Some realities are cherished by their creator, and they don't want that reality to change. Other realities are more for fun or are created as a sandbox for ideas. Some realities are worked on by more than one god, sometimes as a collaborative effort, sometimes as a competitive sport. Many realities have been abandoned by their creator and exists in a half finished state.

Destroying or substantially changing the reality of another god, particularly a reality that they cherish, can result in bloody conflict between the gods. I picture us as gods being like a halfway point between who we are as human beings and the Greek gods of old. We are emotional creatures with wants and desires, we feel pain and remorse, we get greedy and we can be charitable. We have love and we have hate, we can be petty and we all have a sense of arrogance due to our inherent god like abilities.

Gods cannot be killed by anything created inside a reality, but gods can be killed by other gods.

Gods do not age, but if they stay on their own for too long (like an eternity) they will fade away and die.

When a god dies, all their created realities vanish.

---

What rules would you suggest to ensure there is a lasting harmony amongst us gods?

Can there be a lasting harmony amongst us gods?

Or will we end up killing each other off until there is nothing left?

Comment: is this better asked on meta worldbuilding?

Comment: If you can create your own reality and go to it, I don't imagine there is too much need to fight other gods. That is like the best holodeck ever.

Comment: worldbuilding a worldbuilding world with worldbuilders as the builders on worldbuilding.

Comment: To poke at the heart of the matter: are we assuming that there exists one "true reality" in which these rules can be enacted?  What you describe sounds a lot like an idealist world (a philosophy that everything is made of mind, as opposed to physicalism or dualism, which suggest there is matter).  If there is a "true reality" which has a physical component, that dramatically shapes the idealist philosophies that follow for the alternate realities.

Comment: No, this should not be moved to Worldbuilding Meta.

Comment: I would close your reality as opinion based ;)

Comment: This is an interesting mental/logical exercise but I am not sure it can work here.

Comment: Well written, and highly imaginative. I think it might border on too broad, but otherwise I like it.

Comment: I wonder if someone could destroy everyone's realities by changing his/her username to "; drop table Users;"...

Comment: @Frostfyre, I'd go with "; drop table Planets;"

Comment: @CortAmmon you make an excellent point - I have have been toying with whether there should be a single reality that none of the gods can destroy, one where they can meet and hang out at their leisure - a hub reality, kind of like a blend between meta worldbuilding and mount Olympus - and yes, like the other realities it would have a physical component - how do you think this would shape the other realities?

Comment: I find [these rules](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help) are sufficient to promote harmony and weed out discord.  This reality has plenty of room for all other realities that abide by them.  Realities that don't are just a click away for Gods like us so nothing is lost.  What makes this reality nice is that it isn't like the others.

Comment: There already is harmony.

Comment: Lol, the Gods have to obey the [**Be Nice Policy**](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)

Comment: `"completely eliminating anything in those realities except for the gods themselves"` <-- what happens to those Gods? Can they create a new reality, or get shifted to another reality?

Comment: @Mooz they exist in the space between realities? or perhaps back to the hub reality where the gods can freely mingle?

Comment: I think there's a few bits of information missing to answer this question:
How are gods aware of other realities?
Can gods create multiple realities at the same time?
Can gods create an infinite number of realities?
How are gods aware of other gods?
If I can create an infinite number of nearly identical realities and enter one of them, do all other gods know where I am?

Comment: @Shufflepants 1) extra sensory perception, like a short distance radar? 2) no, a god can only be in one reality at a time, you have to be inside a reality to shape it 3) yes 4) us gods are similar to greek gods, we interact in a similar way to humans - plus our ESP mentioned in 1 can be used to detect other gods in the nearby vicinity as well 5) other gods would definitely have a fair amount of searching to do if you hid yourself in identical realities - i love this idea btw

Comment: @Jimmery You've heard of the [Super Cafe](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLimhOT0Avg-Q1zzIFxw0DOcBmDcat4bnK), you've heard of the [Villain Pub](http://www.howitshouldhaveended.com/?s=Villain+Pub), now come and hang out at the the **God Lobby**.

Comment: @Jimmery I'm curious about how you reconcile your answers to gods not being about to create multiple realities at the same time and can gods create an infinite number of realities. If I've created an infinite number of realities, then surely I had to make some of them at the same time. Or did you think I meant "gods can create an arbitrarily large number of realities? Also, how fast is it to create a new universe vs how long it takes to search a reality for another god. And how do you define "nearby vicinity"? And can I create a reality without it having any connections to other realities?

Comment: @Shufflepants 1) you create the realities one at a time - it would be more accurate to say there is no limit to how many realities you can create than to say you can create an infinite number of realities 2) as you should know, world building takes time, and a fully formed reality can easily take years to craft - searching however is far quicker 3) i have left some things intentionally vague (like "near vicinity") to accomodate the wide variety of realities that can be made - lets say you can cover a third of a reality in a day? 4) no, all realities can be travelled to

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Gods - being Gods - wouldn't take too well to rules being imposed on them, especially when the only thing which will entertain them as the eons roll by is their wit.

I submit that practical jokes, and "trolling" would most likely run rampant. However, after a few millennia of realities being randomly wiped out, and countless billions of sentient beings suffering terrible, if highly amusing, fates, a hierarchy might develop.

Some Gods would doubtlessly band together, and elect a few trusted fellows to whom they would grant great, if temporary (in their eyes) powers. These ***Moderators*** would wield mighty ***hammers*** imbued with the power of realities belonging to the Gods who elected them. These hammers would be truly terrible weapons against foes seeking to alter, damage, or ***viciously troll*** those realities from which their power stems.

However, some Gods may very well disagree with the order of things. They may still attempt to challenge the status quo - though in a more cautious, and devious way - employing dark agents known as ***sock-puppets***.

It is entirely possible that some groups of Gods may break away and go create their own coalitions, giving birth to new spheres of influence within which they would seek to limit the power of outsiders. These coalitions, or ***forums***, might then challenge one another and start terrible ***flame-wars*** which would shake the very foundation of the universe, and legends of which (some more accurate than others) would quickly spread to every reality.

And so, the rules of each group may well be very different. Some may seek to promote civility and cooperation, while others may actively encourage mischief, aggression, and other such "entertainment".

I can easily imagine some Gods living double lives as members of multiple forums, being voices of reason and innovation in the one, yet inciting terrible harm in others purely for their own twisted entertainment.

Comment: Love the parallels to this site. Cracks me up xD

Comment: @pleiades - the parable of the internet, lol

Comment: [The many Hammers of SFF.SE](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6464/21267).

Answer (score 5):

Next option the gods do not agree upon rules of laws to cover and all the gods. I think in this case you would see the three different responses or types of gods.

1. The one that universe God  these God's are paranoid in constant fear that there creations will be destroyed. So they stay in one universe and spend all their time checking to see if a rogue God has managed to slip into the universe unseen. If God does tried visit their universe he is met with lethal force.
2. The king of Angels. This type of God creates powerful creatures and gives them some God like abilities. (Think angels, Jin or demons). These creatures aren't strong enough that to kill a god but they can hurt one this would deter Rogue Gods from visiting the universe. Think of it as protecting home within army of robotic fire ants.
3. Alliance makers. These God's would aline them self with other gods with the assurance that if another God messed with one of their universe is the other members group would hunt down and destroy the culprit.

Answer (score 3):

The 5 laws of the divines

1. No divine can enter into the reality of another divines without permission of the of ruling divine.
2. No divine can directly effects the creation of another.
3. The authority we be formed to capture law breaking divines.
4. Those capture will be taken to divine court were they will be in prisoned in a prison universe for a million years.
5. Those who are caught break the law more the four times will be killed

This is if the all the divines form united to agree on rules if I will create another answer detailing what would happen if they don't.